# Excel IF THEN statements

Tags: excel

I have a very large excel sheet with 61000 cells. Daily the amount can differ though most stay the same. I have them sorted alphabetically. I need to find a formula that will look at cell A:1 on 2 different sheets and if A:1 on both sheets are the same it will take cell D:1 on both sheets which is numerical values and get the difference so if D:1 on sheet 1 has a value of 7 and D:1 on sheet 2 has a value of 9 it will print the difference of 2 in another column. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are the values in A1 suppoesd to be matching? If so, sounds like you can use a `VLOOKUP`

Comment: We are in need of more detail. Are you saying specifically `$A$1` as a static cell, or `$A1` to `$A...`? Please [edit] your question to help us help you.

Comment: @Quarinteen, I think Sapan answer will work. If yes can you mark it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have same data in different sheets and some values against them in both the sheets and you want to subtract the values in another sheet.
If so, you can use below steps : 
Use Name Manager and give a name to your table in sheet 1 lets say Data1, give another name to other table in sheet 2 lets say Data2.
Now apply lookup() and subtract them :

=VLOOKUP(A1,Data1,4,0)-VLOOKUP(A1,Data2,4,0)

Hope this will help you.